# I am making a project but this error is coming up and i dont know why

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, nmap

So i created a code to track ips but am getting a error the code is

```
import socket
import os
import sys
import nmap
import time
from datetime import datetime
from urllib import request as urlrequests
def tracker():
    soc = socket.socket()
    Sc = nmap.PortScanner()
    print("[$]----Session started---->")
    ip = input("[?]Enter your I.P to Listen on: ") 
 
    try: 
        host = ip
        port = 80
 
        soc.bind((host, 80))
        print("[+] Listening on "+ ip + "....")
        
    except:
        sys.exit("[!]I.P Busy or any other network issue")
        sys.exit(0)
 
    while True:
                
        try:
            soc.listen(5)
            conn, address = soc.accept()
            print("[+] IP Logged " + str(address[0]))
            recon = Sc.scan(address[0],arguments='-O')
            print(str(address[0]) + " OS details : " + recon['scan'][address[0]]['osmatch'][0]['osclass'][0]['osfamily'])
                        
                                        
        except:
            pass
            print("[^]<----Interrupt occured terminating session---->")
            sys.exit(0)
 
tracker()
```

but its showing a error the error its below i cant understand why its showing this error but am trying to fix it.

```
Import "nmap" could not be resolved from source
```

Comment: check where you have named a file `nmap` and if the python module nmap is actually installed, can you do the import from the REPL prompt (python.exe)

Comment: Are you sure you have `nmap` installed? https://pypi.org/project/python-nmap/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed the package:

[image]

Otherwise you need to install it through: `pip install python-nmap` like deponovo
has mentioned.